# Designing the Layout in opendata.ArcGIS.com

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, data

I am trying to build an open data portal through http://opendata.arcgis.com/, its all the rage right now and pretty exciting development from Esri.

It is fairly new, but it has limited documentation and community support. I would like to completely restyle the site, similar to how http://geo.wa.gov/ or http://data.imap.maryland.gov/ did their sites.

opendata.arcgis allows you to edit the design using their wizard and markdown, or you can customize html (only within the div class="custom-layout" ), the css, and one could insert script tags to extend the html and behaivior:

[image]

To create one of the afore mentioned sites it would take a serious amount of hacking inside their little code editor.

**My Question:** Is there a better way of doing this? Is there a way to download and modify all the code? or do we have to do it all inside this (very) little code editor, using javascript to modify html?

(my rep isn't high enough to create new arcgis-opendata tag or answer my own question)

**EDITED** The solution might be to delete everything in the Header HTML of the "Design Layout" tab and use an iframe with my own css:

```
<div class="header-container">
<iframe src="http://server/remoteHeader.html" 
scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: So, one thing you could try is adding a <style> tag inside of the Layout HTML and start giving elements custom style.  Very similar to editing the Open Data Portal is editing the Home Page for the organization. I've seen this when people want the body to have different background colors, links to have different hover properties, etc.  Regardless, editing the raw HTML for the entire page could be streamlined for those capable, but doing so may open the flood gates for less experienced to inadvertently break functionality on the page.